# Do I need remove adRequest.addTestDevice in production?

Tags: admob

The document does not specify it. I thought we do not need to remove it, because it is our unique device id, the other devices with different id are not impacted. But it is just my guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is correct. When your application is run on a device with that deviceId it will get test ads. All other devices will receive real ads. So you can leave the config in for production.

Comment: This is the correct answer but it's worth noting that its good to see the real ads on your developer device (once your app is live) so you can get a feel that the targeting is good

Comment: Isn't that against the policy to view real ads on your own device? Does Google have a way of knowing you are the developer and you are viewing the ad from your device?

Comment: Google is very vocal about prohibiting viewing ads on your device. Since they know the device on which you have been developing AND adding that as a test device, they can easily catch you. Money and reputation of a corporation is involved in testing live ads so I believe that they will take it very seriously.