# Upload to Google play with AdMob ads

Tags: android, admob

I have an App (I'll call "MyApp" on this post), finished and ready to upload. Also, I already have the code for show the ads.

MyApp code, has the test device id:

```
AdRequest adreq = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("myid").build();
```

So, the first question is: If it's ready to upload, this will be change to:

```
AdRequest adreq = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

This is right?

My other question is about the AdMob and the **ad unit id**.
My ad unit id now, is reference to the app (I'll call AdMobApp) that I got in AdMob dashboard, this adMobApp was created with "Add your app manually" in AdMob. So, if I upload MyApp with the ad unit id of AdMobApp **"manually added"** it will working ok or not?

What the function "Search for your app" do? It put the ads automatically in your app or what?...

That process I don't understand, because, if I search the app(Assuming that MyApp is already on Google Play),  **it will be created ANOTHER ad unit id** So, what happens with the ad unit id that it's on the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do **not** have to remove `addTestDevice("myid")`. This will only mean that after the release, you can download the app and still see the test ads, and not real ads. All other users will see the real ads, as device ID is (almost) unique. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955811/do-i-need-remove-adrequest-addtestdevice-in-production).

Yes, uploading your app with the "manually added" ad unit ID will work. Manually adding is when your app has not yet been released. Searching is for apps that are already released. Since you want to have ads in the app when you release you need to use manual, as you have done. [Source](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/2773509?hl=en):

> Select an app to monetize by using one of the following methods:
>
> a. **Search for your app**: Search Google Play or the iTunes App Store for your app, then click + Monetize.
>
> b. **Add your app manually**: If your app is not published yet, enter the app name and the platform, then click + Monetize.

You do not have to add you app again after you have released, so you will never need to use "Search for your app".

Comment: **Thank you very much!**... I was crazy with that doubt.