# Is this acceptable according to AdMob in android Devices?

Tags: android, admob

I have implemented Interstitial and Banner Ad in my android App, but I had one doubt whether the process followed by me is correct and according to the guidelines or not. Below is the sample Interstitial ad from the emulator:
[image: Ad's on Emulator]

You can see top middle the Test Ad is displayed, however I am using Live Production Publisher id and Ad Unit Id. If the Ad displayed has Test Ad inspite of having the production id's is that ok.

Below are the 2 code snippets:

**Test Device Build**

```
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build());
```

**Live Build**

```
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

I am very much confused between these code snippet as well, both the line in development show Test Ad written on it(Note I am still using live id's).

Now, the strange part is if I run production version of app in emulator it shows test ad in the emulator, but correct ad in actual installation via Play Store.

Can anyone advice me what should be done in this case?

Comment: running the app in emulator always show test ads, you can make sure of this by running an app with ads from google play and you will see it displays test ads

Comment: @humazed so is it safe to use production publisher id and ad unit ad in development environment. Will it not lead to false impression and accidental clicks  ?

Comment: I think it's fine if you run it two or three times to test the ads is working but in general use `addTestDevice` in development.

Comment: @humazed so in the above 2 code snippet you are saying its good to use Test device build version in development, will that suffice?

Comment: yes it's totally ok. take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955811/do-i-need-remove-adrequest-addtestdevice-in-production

Comment: @humazed ok thank you so much for the help. really appreciate it.